# How to Fix Images Not Rendering on the Desired Location

Tags: javascript

I can't put a tile image onto the screen where I want it to actually go. In this case, I want to have 10 images lined side without any gaps.

I have attempted to change the values, alter the images, and use the alert function to debug problems, but I can't find the issue (I'm not a very experienced programmer...).

```
"use strict";
window.onload = function(){
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("mainContainer");
    for(var n = 0; n < 10; n++){
        drawImageOnSpecifiedPosition(0,n*500,0,mainContainer);  
    }
}

function setCoords(x, y, img){
    img.style.position = "absolute";
    img.style.left = x;
    img.style.top = y;
}

function drawImageOnSpecifiedPosition(whichOne, x, y, whereToAppend){
    var imageNames = [
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0001.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0002.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0003.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0004.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0005.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0006.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0007.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0008.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_0009.png",
                     "assets/isometric_pixel_00010.png"
    ];
    var imageToCreate = document.createElement("img");
    imageToCreate.src = imageNames[whichOne];
    setCoords(x, y, imageToCreate);
    whereToAppend.appendChild(imageToCreate);
}
```

I expected to have a line of 10 images side by side. However, what I got back was two images slightly displaced. I did not seem to get any error messages when I checked the console either, so I'm assuming the fault lies in my poor programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't change an elements position by providing a number only.

```
img.style.left = x;
```

The browser expects a measurement. Since we operate at pixel level you need to append a **px**.

```
img.style.left = x + "px";
img.style.top = y + "px";
```

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response. Thanks for the help (it worked)!